# C# with ANTLR4 project

Tags: antlr4

I'm using visualstudio 2008 and do not use nuget.

I would like to port an old ANTLR project to ANTLR4, up to now without success.

Can someone provide detailed instructions and a sample project ?

Comment: Instead of hoping for someone to post a complete step-by-step tutorial, you might get more helpful responses if you actually explain your problem in a bit more detail ("without success" tells us very little).

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a new set of instructions for installing and using the C# target for ANTLR 4. These instructions should provide the necessary information for getting it working with Visual Studio 2008.

https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/wiki/Installation

Comment: as I wrote I am using VS2008 and  the instructions are:TODO: This section needs more detail.

Comment: @user2960717 You are not correct. You could have said the instructions *start with* that line, but your comment suggests that I did not include any additional information. The actual text includes all necessary ANTLR-specific information, and the additional details would just be step-by-step information on using the NuGet console.